How to asynchronously display a splash screen in WinForms while loading the main form in the background (C#)?
I'm working on a WinForms application that includes both WinForms and WPF components. I want to display a splash screen while the main form (frmTP2D) is being loaded asynchronously in the background. The splash screen should remain visible until the main form is fully initialized, and then the splash screen should close, showing the main form.
The issue arises because the main form (frmTP2D) contains both WinForms and WPF elements. Specifically, I use an ElementHost to embed a WPF UserControl (TP3DModelViewer). When initializing the WPF component, I get the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

I've tried using async/await to handle the splash screen and load the main form in the background, but the problem occurs when the WPF components are involved, since they require the main thread to be in STA mode.
I'm using DevExpress for some of the UI components, including the splash screen, and I have [STAThread] set in my Main method. However, I'm still encountering this threading issue when integrating WPF components into the WinForms form.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue when using WPF and WinForms together? Any suggestions on how I can properly initialize the WPF components asynchronously while keeping the splash screen visible?
I have tried to implement asynchronous initialization in my WinForms application by displaying a splash screen while the main form (frmTP2D) loads in the background. My goal was to ensure that the splash screen remains visible until all components of the main form are fully loaded, including the WPF elements embedded using ElementHost. Once the form is ready, I want the splash screen to close and the main form to appear.
To achieve this, I used async/await to load the main form asynchronously, which worked fine until I reached the part of the initialization that involves the WPF elements. The error occurs when trying to initialize the WPF UserControl in a non-STA (Single-Threaded Apartment) context, which WPF requires.
I was expecting to be able to load the form asynchronously and have the splash screen remain visible until the form is completely initialized, but instead, I encountered a threading issue specifically due to the WPF components.
Here’s my InitializeDefaultViews method where the WPF ElementHost is initialized:
private void InitializeDefaultViews()
{
    _GridCanvas = new TPGridCanvas2D(glControl, _GridSettingsManager.GetSettings());
    glControl.Invalidate();

    dckPnl3DView.ControlContainer.Controls.Clear();
    _3DModelViewer = new TP3DModelViewer(_GridSettingsManager.GetSettings());
    var elementHost = new ElementHost
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Child = _3DModelViewer
    };

    dckPnl3DView.ControlContainer.Controls.Add(elementHost);
}


Here’s my Program.cs:
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TPUI
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static Dispatcher _splashScreenDispatcher;
        private static frmTPSplashScreen _splashScreen;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            StartSplashScreen();

            RunInitializationAndMainFormAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static void StartSplashScreen()
        {
            var splashThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                _splashScreenDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

                _splashScreen = new frmTPSplashScreen();
                _splashScreen.Show();

                Dispatcher.Run();
            });

            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            splashThread.Start();
        }

        private static async Task RunInitializationAndMainFormAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            });

            CloseSplashScreen();

            Application.Run(new frmTP2D());
        }

        private static void CloseSplashScreen()
        {
            if (_splashScreenDispatcher != null)
            {
                _splashScreenDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    _splashScreen?.Close();
                });

                _splashScreenDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            }
        }
    }
}



You don't have a threading issue. You are experiencing a PEBKAC issue. You need to limit yourself to a single UI-thread and write your code to accordingly.

So the reason your code fails is simple.  In RunInitializationAndMainFormAsync you are awaiting an operation before having set the Synchronization Context, so the continuation runs in the default context, which will be a thread pool thread, which isn't an STA thread (like the one you called RunInitializationAndMainFormAsync from).
The solution is that the whole fundamental approach is flawed.  Don't create multiple UI threads.  You start the program with a perfectly good STA thread that's designed to be your program's one UI thread.  Use it.
In you main thread you can run an application for your splash screen, then when that finishes, run the application for your "main" form.
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    frmTPSplashScreen splashScreen = new frmTPSplashScreen();
            
    splashScreen.Shown += async (s, a) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        splashScreen.Close();
    };
    Application.Run(splashScreen);
    Application.Run(new frmTP2D());
}


My understanding is that instantiating the frmTP2D form takes time, and the OP wants to display a splash screen during this time. They don't want to display the splash screen just for aesthetic/branding purposes. The splash screen should not be frozen while the frmTP2D is initialized, which means that multithreading is warranted here.

@TheodorZoulias I'm mimicking the code that they provided, but without the bug they mentioned and simplified a lot.  Presumably the delay is not actually a delay, and is instead some long running processing that needs to take place in order to star the program.  In almost every instance someone has claimed that they had long running UI work requiring a second UI thread, the actual problem was performing non-UI work in the UI thread that should have been in a background thread.  The second most common was trying to load too much into controls instead of adding/removing controls on demand.

@TheodorZoulias This is correct (based on what it's shown in the OP). The heavy work in not done in the main Form, it's done in between the time when the Splash Form is shown (which is not frozen here), and when the main Form is presented. You see the RunInitializationAndMainFormAsync() method in the OP, that uses Task.Run() to simulate the work, after that the main Form's message loop is run (though it's not clear if / how this work affects or interact with the Form). The OP needs to handle exceptions, of course, but it's not what has been asked (could be a decent question after)

Loading too many controls, or too much data into controls, is my assumption about the root cause of the OP's problem, but I might be wrong. Solving this problem with a splash screen running on a separate UI thread might be the easiest and less risky solution. The alternative, redesigning the main form with lazy initializations and stuff, is a complex and error-prone endeavor.

@TheodorZoulias The problem that they asked about in the question is that they're trying to start a message loop from a thread pool thread and they're getting an error accordingly.  Their code is being reasonably explicit in finishing their work before even trying to create their second form.  If they actually have a separate problem, beyond the one that they asked about, then that would be a separate question that would require a lot of different information.  We can both guess as to what that missing information might be, but it doesn't mean much.

But since we're guessing for fun, I see way more people performing long running non-UI work on UI threads than I do people actually making so many UI controls that it's a problem.  If they do have too many controls though, the problem with trying to use multiple UI threads to create them is that it still has a really poor user experience, and usage of such a form is likely to be extremely laggy and unresponsive, and not just on construction.  But quality advice would, as mentioned, require lots of information not presented.
